# Yii2, поиск точки входа

Tags: php, yii2, composer, vagrant

Мне предоставили доступ к проекту Yii2. И я не могу понять где находится точка входа в приложение(индексный файл) чтоб указать точку входа для виртуального хоста. И подскажите, как развернуть этот проект у себя на компе, если имеется образ Vagrant, или может как-то через composer.json
Структура проекта следующая:

```
common
    config/              contains shared configurations
    mail/                contains view files for e-mails
    models/              contains model classes used in both backend and frontend
    tests/               contains tests for common classes    
console
    config/              contains console configurations
    controllers/         contains console controllers (commands)
    migrations/          contains database migrations
    models/              contains console-specific model classes
    runtime/             contains files generated during runtime
backend
    assets/              contains application assets such as JavaScript and CSS
    config/              contains backend configurations
    controllers/         contains Web controller classes
    models/              contains backend-specific model classes
    runtime/             contains files generated during runtime
    tests/               contains tests for backend application    
    views/               contains view files for the Web application
    web/                 contains the entry script and Web resources
frontend
    assets/              contains application assets such as JavaScript and CSS
    config/              contains frontend configurations
    controllers/         contains Web controller classes
    models/              contains frontend-specific model classes
    runtime/             contains files generated during runtime
    tests/               contains tests for frontend application
    views/               contains view files for the Web application
    web/                 contains the entry script and Web resources
    widgets/             contains frontend widgets
vendor/                  contains dependent 3rd-party packages
environments/            contains environment-based overrides
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точки входа в вашем случае находятся в:

1. backend/web/index.php
2. frontend/web/index.php
3. yii

Естественно нужно выполнить composer install

Comment: в том то и дело что там нету эти файлов

Comment: Если их нет, то выполните php init в папке с проектом. И они появятся.
Вообще, если вам с этим работать, то рекомендую документацию почитать по yii http://yiiframework.domain-na.me/doc/guide/2.0/ru
И отдельно про расширенное приложение https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/tree/master/docs/guide